# Doughnutchart add a simple '%' to the hover tooltip

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I want to add a '%' to the hover concatenated to my data. So let's say I have:

```
const data = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: false,
  labels: ["a", "b"],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [50, 50],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(12, 29, 213, 0.89)', 'rgba(49, 58, 52, 0.89)'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['#1f2bae','#242825']

    }
  ]
};
```

it displays like this:

[image: Doughnut example]

Now I just want a % concatenated to the 50.
So my question is how do I do this given that I always have the % as data but just as a number without the % ?

Edit: my working solution works like this:

```
tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                      label: function(data ) {
                        var label = data.dataset.label || '';

                        
                        if (data.parsed.y !== null) {
                            label += data.parsed+'%';
                        }
                        return label;
                    }
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: I now have a solution that is like this:

Comment: I kind of have a solution now but I need the tooltipItem.index for it, but once i add the tooltipItem parameter to my function my data doesn't work anymore and I get an error that my data is undefined:
function(tooltipItem, data) causes this error,
function(data) doesn't cause it but I can't get the index of the hovered item